# How to run a notebook in Azure for OpenAI project

Tags: azure, azure-openai

I am following (or trying follow!) the steps in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/openai/tutorials/embeddings?tabs=powershell

I have created `Azure Open AI (aoai)` resource and deployed `open ai` models

Then I opened `PowerShell` in `Azure` and set the environment variables for `key` and `endpoint` for `aoai`. I downloaded the `billsum.csv` data file.

I am now stuck at where to run the `notebook` example - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Azure-OpenAI-Docs-Samples/blob/main/Samples/Tutorials/Embeddings/embedding_billsum.ipynb

I created a `synapse` environment in the same resource group in which I have created `aoai` resources/models and tried to run the first cell of notebook in it. I got error

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [5], line 1
----> 1 import openai
      2 import re
      3 import requests
```

Where do I execute the notebook code?

Comment: Did you check if the libraries/packages are installed in Apache Spark pool?

Comment: If I install libraries using `Powershell`,  won't that make them available to `spark` cluster ?

Comment: I think I found the answer. I have to work on `Azure ML Studio` to use notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Before you run the jupyter cell you need to install the required libraries.

among these libraries:

```
import openai
import re
import requests
import sys
from num2words import num2words
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from openai.embeddings_utils import get_embedding, cosine_similarity
from transformers import GPT2TokenizerFast
```

You need to explicitly install these in your jupyter cell.

```
!pip install openai   
!pip install num2words
!pip install scikit-learn  # this is for openai.embeddings_utils
!pip install transformers
```